# Protect Tasks from modification in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I ensure that a particular scan is run at the end of an Azure Pipeline? The user should not be able to delete/modify this task. I cannot use decorators because they inject jobs across all pipelines in the Azure Organization, or I will need to filter using project names, which is not possible. Is there some other way to make this mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your requirement, the pipeline decorators can directly meet your requirement.

Pipeline decorators also supports to filter using project name.

You can define the if expression in decorator YAML file to filter the projects.

Here is an example:

**my-decorator.yml**

```
steps:
- ${{ if in(variables['System.TeamProject'], '123', 'azure', 'ProjectC') }}:

  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: 'Run my script (injected from decorator)'
    inputs:
      script: 'echo "test"'
```

**Result:**

When the project name meets the filter, it will run the pipeline decorator task.

For example:

[image]

If no, it will not run the pipeline decorator task.

For example:

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Use a decorator to inject steps into a pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-pipeline-decorator?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I did go through this. For this, we need to publish the extension. So if a new project is added..we modify the source code and publish it again..is it? I think decorators might be the only way to have mandatory tasks in the pipeline.

Comment: Yes. You are right. If new project has been added, you need to modify the source code of extension and publish it again.  As far as I know, this is the only way can meet your requirement in Azure DevOps pipeline.